# string truncation in php for pictures URL

Tags: php

I am using a method to extract URLS of OG:Image from head, but iin some ursl, I have funny characters at the end  like this one below.
http://a57.foxnews.com/media2.foxnews.com/BrightCove/694940094001/2016/03/05/0/0/694940094001_4787930541001_e2d19b42-17ef-4294-a6d0-18bc456a3928.jpg?ve=1

HOw I can remove anything after a picture extension like (.jpg, jpeg, gif, png, .bmp ) in php?
Please help me with a code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack OverFlow! Please include your current code to diagnose your problem, thanks

Comment: if you mean funny string ?ve=1 , that it the string coder changes when image changes, so that browsers clean their cache for the image.